# Remote GUI Access to Ubuntu-MATE 16.04

Tags: ssh, gui, mate, xrdp, remote-x-session

I want to access a computer with **Ubuntu-MATE 16.04** from my laptop (running **Windows 10**).
I can use SSH and access it in terminal mode, but sometimes I need to access it using GUI.

Years ago there was a computer in my office running **Ubuntu 10.04** which I had remote GUI access to using [XManager 4](https://www.netsarang.com/products/xmg_overview.html) without any problem, and I am looking for the same experience on the new system with **Ubuntu-MATE 16.04**.

I've tried to use [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) as a free alternative to [XManager 4](https://www.netsarang.com/products/xmg_overview.html), I can access the system in terminal mode but have no success in GUI mode.

I also installed **xrdp** on the system, and then connected to it using **Remote Desktop**, but as my laptop gets a 4K display, the screen lagged and font sizes where so small and un-readable.

So what are the alternative solutions, and how can I access this computer from **Windows 10** in GUI mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can continue using ssh. It can also work with graphics.

```
ssh -X user@ip-adress
```

will let you start graphical application programs in the server, and they will open windows (with lower case w, not the trademark) in your client (on the monitor that you are using). Some programs will work, some will not work. It is easy to check, if the programs you want to use work this way.

Answer (score 0):

I've found Teamviewer a great OS agnostic solution. Depending on your use case, you may need to purchase a license to be in compliance.

https://www.teamviewer.com

Comment: I have thought of it, but he linux system is headless (no monitor), so I believe I shall login to the GUI mode first, and the start the TeamViewer. By the way I think TeamViewer collaboration is over internet, but systems I work with are on the same LAN, so I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: Teamviewer can be used solely on a LAN if desired. If the unit is headless, you'll likely need a dongle to fool the OS into believing there is a display (absolutely necessary in VGA / HDMI motherboards - I can't make that same statement on HDMI but would think so). Here is an example: http://headlessghost.com/